# How to write <= condition in Join transformation in mapping data flow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

So its looks like I can only select `==` option when I want to join 2 data source or stream.
But I want to put some `<,>,<=,>=` condition when I joint 2 data source.
However there is a way to do it by using `Cross Join` but cross join is not an option in my case, I have to use `Outer Join`. Is there any option or suggestion that can help my problem?

[image]
Here is a sample `SQL query` that i actually want to gain, maybe it can help you to understand otherwise you can ignore it just focus the ADF part.

`Select a.col1,a.col2,a.col3,sum(a.col4),b.col0
from T1 a, T2 b
where a.col5 >=b.col1
and a.col5 <= b.col2
group by a.col1,a.col2,a.col3,b.col0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as you said, Data flow [Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-join) only support "`==`" option, we can not change it.

I'm afraid there is no option or good suggestions that can help you solve problem in Data Factory.

Comment: Thanks Leon for your comments.

Comment: @SohelReza You're welcome. Can you please mark is as answer? Or you also can waiting for others  give more information.

Comment: @LeonYue would love your help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59162125/shaping-json-data-in-the-sink